# ASP session between iframe and page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, session, ssl

I have a situation where my `ASP.NET MVC` application can be loaded directly or in `iframe`. It uses `ASP.NET Identity`. When I open the site from `iframe`, log in and after open the site directly it keeps me logged in. Is that a normal behavior? Is session shared between apps opened directly and in `iframe`?

Here are more details: I have a site `https://somesite.com`,
and it can be accessed directly or via another site using `iframe`. I need slightly different designs and functionality depending on where the site is accessed from. I researched and the only good solution seems to have two  different sites: `https://somesite.com`, `https://framed.somesite.com`. I don't need to share sessions between them. Authorization may also work independently. And I need one `SSL certificate` for both sites.

Also, how would you organize projects in `VS2015` in case the design and functionality is mostly the same. Would you have some setting in the config to differentiate and just publish two sites with different settings or would you create two different projects?

Comment: What I was trying to do is differentiate through some session variable. When site is opened from iframe it always hitting some api that sets a variable say 'LoggedFromFrame'. That api is not being hit when I log directly. So I thought I will be able to differentiate by this session variable if site is opened from iframe or directly. But the thing is that they seem to share sessions and when I open directly I am getting the version of site that should be visible when I am logged from frame.

Comment: I meant, why is there a requirement for these two different versions?  Why do you want the iframe version to differ from the normal version?  The actual customer requirement here is highly relevant to the best approach to take.

Comment: Well it is a shopify application. When you open an app from in iframe from shopify site it should work within a concrete shop you logged from. When you log directly you can switch between different shops etc. So there are some menu items that differ and also some pages should not be available etc.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but what is the problem with still being logged in once you go to the main site?  Do you want the users to have two separate accounts?

Comment: @dan1111, well that requirement can be removed I think. The main problem I have is how to differentiate between frame and regular versions. And I thought the best way is to create 2 different sites that work under the same SSL(so it will be subdomained). So sessions will not be shared and that requirement will be automatically fulfilled.

Comment: I can rephrase it like: would be good if we can do this with one site and share sessions, but if we only can do this having 2 different sites and session will not be shared it is also OK(actually it can if we have subdomains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273732/how-can-i-share-a-session-across-multiple-subdomains-in-asp-net). I searched and there are some Javascript code to differentiate, but not stable and I thing it is a bad idea to rely on that code which is not working in all browsers and have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a simple solution. I just created a different sites in `IIS` which were  using the same `SSL` certificate(via subdomains), so I have 2 sites set up in `IIS` `https://somesite.com` and `https://framed.somesite.com`. The second one is just empty and it has a directory pointing to the directory of the first one. So they use the same `SSL` certificate, they have different sessions and some param is being set when opening from `iframe` and so I can differenciate between them.

Answer (score 0):

**There's no problem in the user's session being shared between the two.**  From your comments, it's the same underlying user account.  The point of requiring log in is to authenticate the user, and that has happened.  So don't require it again if they go to the main site.

**Structure it as one project, with the iframe version a subset of the total project.**  The iframe site is a subset of the total functionality.  If you design things right, you will probably use that subset in both your main site and the iframe site.

Comment: Dan, you missed the main point. It is already designed and behaves like you describe. The issue I am facing is how to differentiate between versions? I can not do that via session as it is shared in this case. I can not do that via config setting as it is the same. I can not do that via javascript as it is not reliable.